# Printing items in a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a way to print a set number of items in an array?

So for example, print the first 3 items in $array. Then later on print the next 3 items in $array.

Any suggestions?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function stepArray($array, $step) {
    static $location = 0;

    $started = $location;

    while ($location < ($started + $step) && isset($array[$location])) {
        echo $array[$location];

        $location++;
    }
}
```

That's just off the top of my head, and assumes the array is numbered sequentially. The static variable keeps track of where you were in the array, no matter how many times you call it. So calling

```
stepArray($array, 3);
```

Would print the first three elements, then

```
stepArray($array, 2);
```

Would print the next two, etc.

Comment: (It would also only work for that array, couldn't use another with it.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_slice](http://fr.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-slice.php) to do the work :

```
<?php
$input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");

$output = array_slice($input, 2);         // return "c", "d", et "e"
$output = array_slice($input, -2, 1);     // return "d"
$output = array_slice($input, 0, 3);      // return "a", "b", et "c"
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's something you'd have to build, so depending on what your definition of 'print' is, it could be print_r, var_dump, or just echo, and you can use a function like this as just one example:

```
function printmyarraybythrees($array,$index) {
    for ($x = $index; $x < $index + 3; $x++) print_r($array[$x]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first group:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
echo $array[$i];
```

for the second group:

```
for ($i = 3; $i < 6; $i++)
echo $array[$i];
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I found a few months back was the Array Iterator Class

http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php

You should be able to use this to iterate over an array and pick up where you left off somewhere down the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++) {
    echo $array[$i];
}
```

Then later,

```
for($i=0;$i<6;$i++) {
    echo $array[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Image that your array is as follows:

```
$ary = array('Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Coconut', 'Orange');
```

Now you want to print the first 3. This could be done as follows:

```
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++)
    echo $ary[$i];
```

For the Second 3 you can use the following:

```
for($i=3;$i<6;$i++)
   echo $ary[$i];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ArrayHelper
{
   private static function printArray($from, $to, $array)
   {
     $_new = new Array();
     if($from <= count($array) && $to <= count($array)
     {
     for($i = $to; $i <= $from; $i++)
     {
         $_new[] = $array[$i];
     }
     }
     print_r($_new);
  }
}
$ar = array('One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four');
ArrayHelper::printArray(0, 2);
```